# My output is just giving weird characters

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 3};
        int[] b = {100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105};
        System.out.print(shuffleArrays(a, b));
    }

    public static int[] shuffleArrays(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        int[] c = new int[a.length+b.length];
        for (int i=0; i<b.length-1; i++)
        {
            if (i<a.length-1 && i<b.length-1)
                c[i] = c[i] + (a[i] + b[i]);
            else if (i>=a.length-1)
                c[i] = c[i] + b[i];
            else if (i>=b.length-1)
                c[i] = c[i] + a[i];
        }

        return c;
    }
```

This is giving me an output of "[I@1837b90c". No idea why this is happening. Am I calling on the method incorrectly?

Comment: Use `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(shuffleArrays(a, b)));`

Comment: Cannot find symbol Arrays

Comment: then `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: Why do you need to repeat `c[i] +` continuously instead of using `c[i] +=`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing the reference to the array that is returned by `shuffleArrays`.  This does not automatically print out the contents of the array, but instead prints the array reference.  You would want to do something like the following:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(shuffleArrays(a, b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you have the wrong method, this one is working fine :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    int[] b = {100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105};
    //c[] = {0, 100, 1, 101, 2, 102, 3, 103, 104, 105}
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(shuffleArrays(a, b)));
}

public static int[] shuffleArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
       public static int[] shuffleArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int[] smaller;
    int[] bigger;
    if (a.length < b.length){
        smaller = a;
        bigger = b;
    } else {
        smaller = b;
        bigger = a;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < smaller.length; i++) {
        c[i*2] = smaller[i];
        c[i*2+1] = bigger[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bigger.length - smaller.length; i++) {
        c[smaller.length*2+i] = bigger[smaller.length+i];
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: This gave incorrect output.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt noticed, I am blind. However I reworked that with much better solution, which I tested properly and it works :). I edited my answer, so take a look.